# Unwanted Cross Join in JPA CriteriaQuery select in subquery

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I'm getting what I think are needless CROSS JOINs when I'm doing a select IN SUBQUERY, which is hurting performance.  I'm using Postgres if that makes a difference.

I'm aiming to generate the following query

```sql
select a1.first_name from author a1
where a1.last_name = ?
  and (a1.id in
       (select distinct b.author_id
        from book b    
          where (b.published_on between ? and ?)
        group by b.author_id
        having count(b.author_id) >= 2))
```

But I get

```sql
select a1.first_name from author a1
where a1.last_name = ?
  and (a1.id in
       (select distinct b.author_id
        from book b
          cross join author a2 where b.author_id = a2.id -- <<< I don't want this cross join!
          and (b.published_on between ? and ?)
        group by b.author_id
        having count(b.author_id) >= 2))
```

Code

```java
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(Author.class);
        Root<Author> authorRoot = cq.from(Author.class);

        Subquery<Long> countSubquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<Book> bookRoot = countSubquery.from(Book.class);
        Expression<Long> count = cb.count(bookRoot.get(Book_.author));

        countSubquery.select(bookRoot.get(Book_.AUTHOR))
            .distinct(true)
            .where(cb.between(bookRoot.get(Book_.publishedOn),
                LocalDate.of(2021, MARCH, 1),
                LocalDate.of(2021, MARCH, 31)))
            .groupBy(bookRoot.get(Book_.author))
            .having(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(count, 2L));

        cq.where(
            cb.equal(authorRoot.get(Author_.lastName), "Smith"),
            cb.in(authorRoot.get(Author_.ID)).value(countSubquery));

        cq.select(authorRoot.get(Author_.FIRST_NAME));

        TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

        return query.getResultList();
```

In reality I'm generating the queries from a user driven query builder, this code recreates the exact problem I'm having.

When using the query builder the user could end up with multiple select in subqueries so I need this to perform as well as possible.

I don't see why I should need any join/cross join for my query to work.

Entities

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Book> books;

}

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    private LocalDate publishedOn;
    
}
```

Comment: The Criteria API merely generates a JPQL query, and I don't see any conditional logic within that part, which means you can skip it and just use the JPQL query directly. It would make sense to use it if you have to generate various `where`, `having` or `order by` conditions. As it is now, you don't need it.

Comment: The `TypedQuery<Author>` will give you problems, though. The returned type is `String`, not `Author`

Comment: @coladict The TypedQuery<Author> does work/compiles, and successfully returns Strings!  I think this is due to type erasure at runtime

Comment: Code updated to have CriteriaQuery<String> and TypedQuery<String>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression: `bookRoot.get(Book_.author)` means you're joining `Author` to `Book` implicitly.

To get rid of the extra join, you would have to either use a native query, or map `Book.author_id` once more as a simple column:

```
@Column(name = "author_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long authorId;
```

And use `Book_.authorId` instead.

Comment: Thanks @crizzis - I made the Long authorId a read only property to ensure it can't be changed.  This then works beautifully as "author_id" is the default name of join column for Author author.  I might update the example to have a JoinColumn on Author author to make that bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue would be solved just by using `join` instead of `get` in `bookRoot.get(Book_.author)`. You're referencing `Author` (a relation attribute, not a basic attribute) without an explicit join. That will make the persistence provider to generate a `cross join` instead of an `inner join`.